# Thunderbird 68: CSS to change Quote Colours

Tags: thunderbird

in older Thunderbird, I used the addon "QuoteColors", which nicely color quoted text in emails. With Thunderbird 68, this addon is no loner compatible, so I am trying to achieve the same with `css`:

This is my `userContent.css`

```
blockquote[type=cite] {
  border-color: #ff3f55 ! important;
  color: #ff463a ! important;
  background: #454545;  ! important;
}

blockquote[type=cite] blockquote {
  border-color: #fad123 ! important;
  color: #fad123 ! important;
  background: #656565;  ! important;
}

blockquote[type=cite] blockquote blockquote {
  border-color: #3022f0 ! important;
  color: #1e0fe4 ! important;
  background: #858585;  ! important;
}
```

This works very nicely, but only in the main window.

When I click "reply" and the compose window opens, the quoted text is unaffected.

How can I use my `css` colors, to change the quoted text in com,pose window as well ?

I am using plaintext format in the compose window, in case that's relevant.

Comment: plaintext format cannot take css style defined formatting

Comment: @αғsнιη  - when I used the QuoteColors addon in earlier version, it worked with plaintext as well

Comment: @400-the-cat hehe :D you should of tagged me directly lol i'll post the solution later today ;) αғsнιη may be right about the plaintext thing but there is probably an other way around

Comment: @intika - we meet again, old friend. I new I could rely on you.

Comment: @400theCat i am updating quotecolors extension to make it compatible v68x... with `userContent.css` that wont be easy because of the plaintext format (no css)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Thunderbird addon**

I just updated the extension *QuoteColors*; it is released under the name *New QuoteColors*, note that the extension's xpi file is signed to ease the installation. The extension does not handle the message composer/editor, this require additional work to make it compatible with that section, i will edit my answer later on if i have the time to work on this.

*Sources & site: [Github page](https://github.com/Intika-Firefox-Addons/thunderbird-quote-colors)*

*Download: [v0.3.5 release](https://github.com/Intika-Firefox-Addons/thunderbird-quote-colors/releases) (compatible v60.x and v68.x)*

*Mozilla addons site: [addons.thunderbird.net](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-us/thunderbird/addon/new-quotecolors/) (still under review)*

---

**Custom CSS:**

Customizing the message composer while in plain-text mode is not an easy task as plain-text editing does not have any css and thus can not handle css customisations, **BUT** this depend on the way you are applying plain-text because Thunderbird can be setup to compose the message in html while sending it in plain-text.

*please test the following code and let me know ;) note that this is an exhaustive custom CSS list for the matter from TB v68.4.1 for testing purpose while technical details about your setup are missing*

```
span[_moz_quote=true] {
  color: green !important;
  background: green !important;
  background-color: green !important;
  border-color: green !important;
}

pre[_moz_quote=true] {
  color: green !important;
  background: green !important;
  background-color: green !important;
  border-color: green !important;
}

/* :::: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ::::: */

/* ::::: message text, incl. quotes ::::: */

.moz-text-flowed blockquote,
.moz-text-plain blockquote {
  border-color: red !important;
  color: red !important;
  background: red !important;
  background-color: red !important;
}

.moz-text-plain pre {
  border-color: red !important;
  color: red !important;
  background: red !important;
  background-color: red !important;
}

.moz-text-plain[wrap="true"] {
  color: red !important;
  background: red !important;
  background-color: red !important;
  border-color: red !important;
}

.moz-text-plain[wrap="false"] {
  color: red !important;
  background: red !important;
  background-color: red !important;
  border-color: red !important;
}

.moz-text-plain[wrap="flow"] .moz-txt-sig {
  color: red !important;
  background: red !important;
  background-color: red !important;
  border-color: red !important;
}

.moz-text-plain[graphical-quote="false"] blockquote {
  color: red !important;
  background: red !important;
  background-color: red !important;
  border-color: red !important;
}

.moz-text-plain[graphical-quote="true"] .moz-txt-citetags {
  color: red !important;
  background: red !important;
  background-color: red !important;
  border-color: red !important;
}

.moz-txt-underscore {
  color: red !important;
  background: red !important;
  background-color: red !important;
  border-color: red !important;
}

.moz-txt-formfeed {
  color: red !important;
  background: red !important;
  background-color: red !important;
  border-color: red !important;
}

/* :::: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ::::: */

body.light blockquote {
  border-inline-start: 2px solid blue !important;
  color: red !important;
  background: red !important;
  background-color: red !important;
  border-color: red !important;
}

body.sepia blockquote {
  border-inline-start: 2px solid blue !important;
  color: red !important;
  background: red !important;
  background-color: red !important;
  border-color: red !important;
}

body.dark blockquote {
  border-inline-start: 2px solid blue !important;
  color: red !important;
  background: red !important;
  background-color: red !important;
  border-color: red !important;
}

.moz-reader-content blockquote {
  color: red !important;
  background: red !important;
  background-color: red !important;
  border-color: red !important;
}

/* :::: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ::::: */

body blockquote[type=cite] {
  color: red !important;
  background: red !important;
  background-color: red !important;
  border-color: red !important;
}

/* :::: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ::::: */

body blockquote[type=cite] {
  color: red !important;
  background: red !important;
  background-color: red !important;
  border-color: red !important;
}

blockquote[type=cite] blockquote[type=cite] {
  color: red !important;
  background: red !important;
  background-color: red !important;
}

blockquote[type=cite] blockquote[type=cite] blockquote[type=cite] {
  color: red !important;
  background: red !important;
  background-color: red !important;
  border-color: red !important;
}

blockquote[type=cite] blockquote[type=cite] blockquote[type=cite] blockquote[type=cite] {
  color: red !important;
  background: red !important;
  background-color: red !important;
}

blockquote[type=cite] blockquote[type=cite] blockquote[type=cite] blockquote[type=cite] blockquote[type=cite] {
  color: red !important;
  background: red !important;
  background-color: red !important;
}

/* :::: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ::::: */

.moz-email-headers-table,
.moz-email-headers-table > tbody > tr > th,
.moz-email-headers-table > tbody > tr > td,
blockquote[type=cite] table,
blockquote[type=cite] table > tbody > tr > th,
blockquote[type=cite] table > tbody > tr > td {
  border: 1px solid transparent !important;
  color: red !important;
  background: red !important;
  background-color: red !important;
  border-color: red !important;
}

table.moz-email-headers-table:hover,
table.moz-email-headers-table:hover > tbody > tr > th,
table.moz-email-headers-table:hover > tbody > tr > td,
blockquote[type=cite] table:hover,
blockquote[type=cite] table:hover > tbody > tr > th,
blockquote[type=cite] table:hover > tbody > tr > td {
  color: red !important;
  background: red !important;
  background-color: red !important;
  border-color: red !important;
}

/* :::: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ::::: */

body > p:-moz-first-node, td > p:-moz-first-node, th > p:-moz-first-node,
body > dl:-moz-first-node, td > dl:-moz-first-node, th > dl:-moz-first-node,
body > multicol:-moz-first-node, td > multicol:-moz-first-node, th > multicol:-moz-first-node,
body > blockquote:-moz-first-node, td > blockquote:-moz-first-node, th > blockquote:-moz-first-node,
body > h1:-moz-first-node, td > h1:-moz-first-node, th > h1:-moz-first-node,
body > h2:-moz-first-node, td > h2:-moz-first-node, th > h2:-moz-first-node,
body > h3:-moz-first-node, td > h3:-moz-first-node, th > h3:-moz-first-node,
body > h4:-moz-first-node, td > h4:-moz-first-node, th > h4:-moz-first-node,
body > h5:-moz-first-node, td > h5:-moz-first-node, th > h5:-moz-first-node,
body > h6:-moz-first-node, td > h6:-moz-first-node, th > h6:-moz-first-node,
body > listing:-moz-first-node, td > listing:-moz-first-node, th > listing:-moz-first-node,
body > plaintext:-moz-first-node, td > plaintext:-moz-first-node, th > plaintext:-moz-first-node,
body > xmp:-moz-first-node, td > xmp:-moz-first-node, th > xmp:-moz-first-node,
body > pre:-moz-first-node, td > pre:-moz-first-node, th > pre:-moz-first-node,
body > ul:-moz-first-node, td > ul:-moz-first-node, th > ul:-moz-first-node,
body > menu:-moz-first-node, td > menu:-moz-first-node, th > menu:-moz-first-node,
body > dir:-moz-first-node, td > dir:-moz-first-node, th > dir:-moz-first-node,
body > ol:-moz-first-node, td > ol:-moz-first-node, th > ol:-moz-first-node {
  color: red !important;
  background: red !important;
  background-color: red !important;
  border-color: red !important;
}
```

Comment: @400-the-cat [ChangeQuote](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-us/thunderbird/addon/changequote/?src=search) can be used to enforce replying in text mode...

Comment: the first block (the first 6 lines) does basically 95% of what I needed. I have no idea what the rest of the code is for.

Comment: @400-the-cat I bet that one would work it's why i put it at first :D ... other code are for `quote` in different situation depending on the setup (i posted all/any editable code for `quote` for v68). what's the missing 5% ? can you update the question with some captures.

Comment: here is a screenshot: https://ibb.co/JBz9cGb as it looks now (using your first 6 lines). Ideally, the different levels of reply should be able to be colored differently (,ie `<`, `<<`). Also the first line starting with `>` is not colored. But these are details.

Comment: @400theCat thanks for the bounty, i appreciate it, i still have this on my todo for this week, i will comment back here later on for the missing 5% ;)